# problem occurs when I use ListView inside Stack(Positoned)

Tags: flutter, dart

I want display three things in the screen, a timeTable that show date, a `ListView` containing several `Container` and a navigation bar in the bottom of the screen.The reason why I put them in a `Stack` is the `ListView` is longer than screen size and I don't want it block the navigation bar. My question is about the content of `ListView` don't display at all, so as the bottom navigation bar just blank. I have tried to replace the `ListView` with `Column`, it works but isn't what I want. And the error=

> RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#40da3
> relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
> 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1694
> pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              child: timeTable(),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 114.0,
              height: 200,
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(height: 100,),
                  Container(height: 100,),
                ],
              )
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: NavigationBar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

below is about timeTable() class

```
    Widget timeTable() {
  return Container(
    height: 98.0,
    width: 540.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 114.0, right: 114.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(height: 24.0,),
        Container(
          height: 24.0,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Text('日付', style: StatisticTextStyle.date, ),
              ),
              stuckButtons(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
          height: 44,
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
            child: RichText(
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "2020年10月15日 ",
                    style: StatisticTextStyle.mainText,
                  ),
                  WidgetSpan(
                    // make the icon higher so that alignment with the text.
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                      child: MyIcon.calendarIcon,
                    )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: hard to understand what you trying to achieve here. Maybe share us some screenshot ?

Comment: Did you tried wrapping your listview with `expanded`  widget

Comment: post the whole code to easily copy paste and reproduce the bug on dartpad

Comment: @JohnJoe so sorry, I'm new in stackoverflow, I have re-editted my question. Please check it again. Thank you for reminding.

Comment: @AR I tried your solution just now, it seems to work a bit, content of `ListView` and bottom navigaiton bar dispalyed, but  the `timeTable` disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.
The reason why I choose `Stack` is regarding customized bottom navigation bar as a widget belongs to body. Actually, we can use `bottomNavigationBar` in Scaffold.
So the problem left is how to maintain a widget and a `ListView` in a `Column` to display in the screen.
new error information=

> The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Vertical
> viewport was given unbounded height.
> it's not difficult to find we should give the `ListView` a height. Put the `ListView` into a `container` and set the height of the `container` then it will be Okay.